# Getting asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, google-cloud-pubsub, publish-subscribe

I have a python application which is running inside a uvicorn server. I have created a Pub/sub subscriber and trying to enable it from my main.py. I am using a streaming-pull subscription. Now, my requirement is that once the subscriber is created, control should come back to main.py instead of getting blocked in the subscriber listening for events

The code for my subscriber is as follows-

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from app.services.subscription_service import save_bill_events
from app.utils import constants
from app.utils.logging_tracing_manager import get_logger
import traceback

print("Entered in bill_subscriber----------------------")
logger = get_logger(__file__)


def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    save_bill_events(message.data)
    message.ack()


async def create_bill_subscriber():
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path("{projectId}",
                                                     constants.BILL_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
    # Limit the subscriber to only have fixed number of  outstanding messages at a time.
    flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=50)
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback, flow_control=flow_control)
    with subscriber:
        try:
            # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
            # unless an exception is encountered first.
            streaming_pull_future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            # Even in case of an exception, subscriber should keep listening
            logger.error(
                f"An error occurred while pulling message from subscription {constants.BILL_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}",
                exc_info=True)
            traceback.print_exc()
            pass
```

From my main.py, I am trying to call above method using asyncio

```
asyncio.run(main=bill_subscriber.create_bill_subscriber())
```

But I am seeing an error `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`. Am I not using `asyncio.run()` in a correct way?

Is there any chance uvicorn runs the application within an event loop and therefore we can't start another event loop? If it is the case, is there any other way to start the subscriber in the background?

Comment: Please include the complete code that shows how you call `create_bill_subscriber` using `asyncio.run()`.

Comment: asyncio.run(main=bill_subscriber.create_bill_subscriber())

Comment: No, I mean please include the contents of `main.py`

Comment: There isn't anything else in the main.py. The development is just started and first thing we are doing is the Pub/sub subscription. Other components will be added later

Comment: You must surely have imports in order to call the create_bill_subscriber function!?

Comment: Yes, those are there, otherwise it would not have got called and resulted in error

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance uvicorn runs the application within an event loop
> and therefore we can't start another event loop? If it is the case, is
> there any other way to start the subscriber in the background?

Yes, the whole idea of `uvicorn` is that it runs an asyncio loop, and one can optionally write their views as async co-routines - and then it does use one asyncio task per request, instead of a much more expensive, in system resource terms, thread.

One can simply add new tasks to the running asyncio loop used by uvicorn, and just take some care to handle the trail of tasks created outside of the "tasks as request-views" default. Python's asyncio model is actually designed for that.

You only have to change the call to your function, so that
it works from inside and already running loop

```
import asyncio
...

my_tasks = set()

def someview(...):
     ...
     # instead of:
     # asyncio.run(main=bill_subscriber.create_bill_subscriber())
     task = asyncio.create_task(bill_subscriber.create_bill_subscriber())
     my_tasks.add(task)
     task.add_done_callback(my_tasks.discard)
     ...
```

The idea of having a set to hold your tasks that should keep running after a view returns, is that asyncio needs you to keep a reference to such tasks. The callback above to remove the reference to it when it is done should be enough to avoid any resource leaking.

Also, depending on what you are doing in your tasks, you might want to run then in a custom context - check https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html to understand that part, if you feel the need for it.

Comment: Should the function someview directly called from my main.py?

Comment: yes - or, just add the 3 lines above to your main.py directly.